# Do I need a transit visa in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens, kul

I am a Sri Lankan passport holder and I'm planning to visit Bangkok from Trichy, India with Air Asia or Malindo Air. Do I need a transit visa at Kuala Lumpur International Airport on arrival?

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic*, the database used airlines, you do need a transit visa for Malaysia, as well as the Thai visa.

> Passport holder of Sri Lanka
>   **Destination   Thailand**
>   Transit countries/territories   Malaysia
>
> **Visa & passport information**
>   Destination - Thailand (TH)
>   **Passport**
>   Passport required.
>
> **Passport Exemptions**:
>   Nationals of Sri Lanka with an emergency passport.
>
> **Document Validity:**
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>
> When nationals of Sri Lanka travel with an emergency passport, it must be valid for a minimum of 30 days from the arrival date.
>
> **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Passengers with a transit visa issued by Thailand for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must have a confirmed onward ticket to a third country.
>
> **Additional Information:**
>   Visitors over 12 years of age with a visa must hold sufficient funds to cover their stay (at least THB 20,000.- per person or THB 40,000.- per family). Proof of funds includes Letters of Credit, vouchers, MCO's or well-known credit cards, which are honored in Thailand.
>
> **Warning:**
>   Visitors who are visa exempt but do not hold return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
>
> **Transit - Malaysia (MY)**
>   **Visa**
>   Visa required.

*Courtesy of [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) web site sharing of the tool.